# SQL query add custom value to select based on distinct column value

Tags: sql-server

I have this table from a subquery select:

```
Name    ResultType    TestID
Guy1    Result A      1
Guy1    Result B      1
Guy1    Result C      1
Guy1    Result A      2
Guy1    Result C      2
Guy1    Result B      3
Guy2    Result A      4
Guy2    Result C      4
Guy3    Result D      5
Guy3    Result A      6
--ETC
```

A list of testIDs, results they got and the name of the user.
I want to be able to get this in the SELECT statement:

```
Name    ResultType    TestID    WhichTestNumberWasIt
Guy1    Result A      1         1
Guy1    Result B      1         1
Guy1    Result C      1         1 --The first distinct TestID for this user
Guy1    Result A      2         2
Guy1    Result C      2         2 --The second
Guy1    Result B      3         3 --And third
Guy2    Result A      4         1 --This is the first distinct TestID for this user
Guy2    Result C      4         1 
Guy3    Result D      5         1 --Again, same distinct TestID for another user
Guy3    Result A      6         2
--ETC
```

Preferably during the SELECT statement because this is a subquery from a JOIN that's inside a `()` and it's quite sizeable already (I omitted a bunch of columns here).

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Whats the logic to calculate distinct testid?

Comment: @SanjayGoswami This is part of a `PIVOT` query and I need to group the `TestID` by distinct values so I can pivot them regardless of the User (since the `TestID` values is auto-incrementing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    NAME VARCHAR(100),
    RT VARCHAR(50),
    testid INT
)

Insert into #tmp values('Guy1','Result A',1)
Insert into #tmp values('Guy1','Result B',1)
Insert into #tmp values('Guy1','Result C',1)
Insert into #tmp values('Guy1','Result A',2)
Insert into #tmp values('Guy1','Result C',2)
Insert into #tmp values('Guy1','Result B',3)
Insert into #tmp values('Guy2','Result A',4)
Insert into #tmp values('Guy2','Result C',4)
Insert into #tmp values('Guy3','Result D',5)
Insert into #tmp values('Guy3','Result A',6)


SELECT *,DENSE_RANK()   Over( PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY TestID ASC) as Rank FROM #tmp
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DENSE_RANK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173825.aspx) to get this:

```
SELECT  Name,
        ResultType,
        TestID,
        TestNumber = DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY TestID)
FROM    <Subquery>;
```

<del>**Example on SQL Fiddle**</del>

**Full Example**

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#T', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #T;

CREATE TABLE #T ([Name] VARCHAR(4), [ResultType] VARCHAR(8), [TestID] INT)
INSERT INTO #T ([Name], [ResultType], [TestID])
VALUES
    ('Guy1', 'Result A', 1),
    ('Guy1', 'Result B', 1),
    ('Guy1', 'Result C', 1),
    ('Guy1', 'Result A', 2),
    ('Guy1', 'Result C', 2),
    ('Guy1', 'Result B', 3),
    ('Guy2', 'Result A', 4),
    ('Guy2', 'Result C', 4),
    ('Guy3', 'Result D', 5),
    ('Guy3', 'Result A', 6);

SELECT  Name,
        ResultType,
        TestID,
        TestNumber = DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY TestID)
FROM    #T
ORDER BY Name, TestID;
```

Comment: Hey I am slow, I did bit work so post on it... I did not copied

Comment: Thank you too! Although you were 3 min late hehe